kotlin android studio scrollbar issues
I am working on a project in Android Studio where I have a form on which I need to place a scroll function (scrollbar) however, when I apply it and execute the scroll it does not happen, no matter how much I try to scroll the screen it stays fixed.
below is the activity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33b8ff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/LOGO"
            android:layout_width="287dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:translationX="20dp"
            android:translationY="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crear cliente"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="110dp"
            android:translationY="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="333dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="ID"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="80dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tipoId"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Tipo ID"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="120dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nombre"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Nombre"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="160dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/direccion"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Direccion"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="200dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/telefono"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Telefono"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="240dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ciudad"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Ciudad"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="280dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/formaPago"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Froma de pago"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="320dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/correoFe"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Correo para factura"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="360dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/crearCliente"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:text="Crear Cliente"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="40dp"
            android:translationY="400dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/moduloFactura"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:text="Modulo Facturas"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:translationX="230dp"
            android:translationY="400dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

This is the graphical representation
thanks
I have searched for a lot of information but nothing I have tried has worked.

You can fix the scrolling issue by replacing translationX and translationY with layout_margin. This change ensures proper spacing and scrollability within the ScrollView.
Instead of using:
android:translationX="**dp"
android:translationY="**dp"

Use:
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"


Thank you very much, that is the solution.
Blessings.

You're welcome, Blessings to you as well.
